# bing map v7 to v8 migration - script importing issue

Tags: javascript, web, bing, bing-maps

Ok so I have looked around for a solution for this and I am sure someone will say that is a duplicate topic but I am very confused as to why this doesn't work.

This is a basic example of the code I have right now

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var url = 
    //'http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=GetMap';
    'https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol';
    loadScript(url, test_function);
    function test_function() {
        console.log('inside test_function before map');
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'My Bing Maps Key'});
        console.log('inside test_function after map');
    };
</script>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        console.log('inside IE block');
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        console.log('inside Other block');
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

**Console output**

```
main.js:18 inside Other block
main.html:17 inside test_function before map
mapcontrol:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null
    at k (mapcontrol:11)
    at n.h [as create] (mapcontrol:11)
    at e (mapcontrol:11)
    at t.l [as instance] (mapcontrol:11)
    at n.h [as create] (mapcontrol:11)
    at e (mapcontrol:11)
    at t.l [as instance] (mapcontrol:11)
    at new Microsoft.Maps.Map (mapcontrol:13)
    at test_function (main.html:18)
    at HTMLScriptElement.script.onload (main.js:20)
```

I can get a basic example working but when I try to do this method of creating the script element and appending it I get nothing. Since this is the way it was implemented in the larger application that this came from in v7 I am not trying to re-architect it.

I have tried things like jQuery getScript and what not.

Please let me know what you think!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I can think to say is that you should probably remove your credentials from your publicly posted question. Just a thought.

Secondly, the error is due to attempting to interact with the map before the map is loaded.

I've personally never seen a script loaded in that manner before, but I guess it works - at least in some cases, but probably not this one. I assume you have a reason for doing it in such a way.

Anyway, with my lack of knowledge about it, I can only assume that what is happening is that the script is being loaded and your callback (test_function) is being called as the code appears to suggest it does.

However, the *script* being loaded and *Bing Maps* being loaded are, I suspect, two different things in this case.

Your initially commented out url with the `&callback=GetMap` is the documented way of async loading Bing Maps. Your `GetMap` function will be called by Bing Maps once it has finished loading. With this particular code, `callback=test_function` would be what you want.

So `test_function` should be initiated by Bing Maps itself, not being passed through your script loading function (again, making assumptions about how it works). The loading function, I guess, doesn't actually want to do anything other than get that script in place, so no callback method; Bing Maps will handle that for you.

Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6nb7cTaQikU7Ay463c3x) for you of it working.